# C*-Algebras: Contractive Morphism

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

**Problem**

Given C*-algebras $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ with $\mathbb{1}_\mathcal{A}\in\mathcal{A}$.

Consider an algebraic morphism $\pi:\mathcal{D}\subseteq\mathcal{A}\to\mathcal{B}$ with $\mathbb{1}_\mathcal{A}\in\mathcal{D}$.
*(More precisely, it is a *-morphism on a *-subalgebra.)*

> Is it contractive then:
>   $$\|\pi[A]\|\leq\|A\|$$

The problem is that the domain may not be closed.

Moreover, the target space may have no identity at all.

Besides, the morphism may not preserve identities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I'm writing this as an answer to have a little more space to write.*

What you want to prove is not true: for a $*$-homomorphism to be necessarily contractive, you need the domain to be a C$^*$-algebra.

For instance, let $\mathcal A=C[0,1]$, $\mathcal B=\mathbb C$, $\mathcal D=\{\text{polynomials}\}$, and $\pi(p)=p(2)$. Then $\pi$ is clearly a $*$-homomorphism. And it is unbounded:
$$
\|x^n\|=1,\ \ \pi(x^n)=2^n,\ \ \ n\in\mathbb N.
$$
Of course, this $\pi$ cannot be extended continuously to $\mathcal A$.

And this illustrates what I was mentioning in the comments: when you try to consider the inverses of polynomials, those inverses--when they exist--are not polynomials.

Comment: I see your counterexample. But then there must be a flaw in my details. Can you have a look at my details, please?

Comment: Ah, ok got it: The inverse may not be part of the domain.

Comment: That clarifies my concerns. Thanks a lot!!! :)

Comment: Your details omit $\mathcal D $. You are assuming that $ \pi $ is defined on all of $\mathcal A $, which is a C $^*$-algebra. In that case $\pi $ is indeed contractive via the proof you provided,  which is the standard one.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

**Remark**

As shown in the answer above the domain must be all. Thanks alot @Martin Argerami!! :)

**Proof**

Suppose the domain is all $\mathcal{D}=\mathcal{A}$.

Choose a C*-subalgebra with identity:
$$\mathrm{im}\pi\subseteq\mathcal{C}\subseteq\mathcal{B}:\quad1_\mathcal{C}=\pi[1_\mathcal{A}]$$

A minimal candidate is the closure of the image:
$$\mathcal{C}_\text{min}=\overline{\mathrm{im}\pi}$$
and a maximal candidate is the projection onto:
$$P:=\pi[\mathbb{1}_\mathcal{A}]:\quad\mathcal{C}_\text{max}=P\mathcal{B}P$$
*(These really can differ!)*

So one has:
$$\lambda\in\rho_\mathcal{A}(A)\implies(A-\lambda1_\mathcal{A})(A-\lambda1_\mathcal{A})^{-1}=1_\mathcal{A}\text{ & vice versa}\\
\implies\pi[A-\lambda1_\mathcal{A}]\cdot\pi[(A-\lambda1_\mathcal{A})^{-1}]=\pi[1_\mathcal{A}]=1_\mathcal{C}\text{ & vice versa}\implies\lambda\in\rho_\mathcal{C}(\pi[A])$$
Note that: $\pi[A-\lambda1_\mathcal{A}]=\pi[A]-\lambda1_\mathcal{C}$

And therefore:
$$\|\pi[A]\|^2=\|\pi[A^*A]\|=r_\mathcal{C}(\pi[A^*A])\leq r_\mathcal{A}(A^*A)=\|A^*A\|=\|A\|^2$$
*(Note that the last both equalities turn into inequalities for involutive Banach algebras.)*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18845/discussion-on-answer-by-freeze-s-c-algebras-contractive-morphism).

Comment: I really fail to see what would be the negative impact of those comments been here as opposed to the chat.